# jquery-atwho-railsを使っていますが、Uncaught TypeError: $(...).atwho is not a functionとでます。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, coffeescript

https://gorails.com/episodes/at-mentions?autoplay=1#　を参考に、メンション機能を実装していますが、Uncaught TypeError: $(...).atwho is not a functionというエラーがでます。

[image: エラー画面]

comments.coffee

```
jQuery ->
   $('[data-behavior="autocomplete"]').atwho(
     at: "@",
    'data': 'a'
 )
```

applicaiton.js,application.css,_form.html.erbの設定は、完了しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このコードは.atwhoを使うために必要です：

```
<link href="css/jquery.atwho.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.atwho.js"></script>
```